# how to iterate in a string in python?

Tags: python

I want to make some montage in `ImageMagick` which is called by Python via `os.system()` with 100 jpegs files.

Here's the command:

```
cmd='montage '+file[i]+' '+file[i+1]+' '+file[i+2]+' '+file[u+3]+'     +file[i+4]+'...+file[i+99]
```

I would like to know how could I avoid to write all `file[i+x]` entries.
Is this possible?

Comment: cmd = "montage " + " ".join(files) Assuming all your filenames are in 'file'

Comment: Use subprocess() instead. os.system() is really, really outdated. Proposed depricated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To join 100 strings with a space starting at `i`th index:

```
cmd = "montage " + " ".join(file[i:i+100])
```

.. where `file[i:i+100]` will return a sub-sequence starting at i, and ending at (i + 100 - 1)

Comment: Downvoted before you added the first explanation, just one line of code is not enough for a good answer for me. Now it's good